# How to correctly print unicode math powers

Tags: java, unicode

I would like to format a number raised to a power using unicode characters.
The thing is that I have to parse first a String containing `^` symbols and the powers next to it

I understand that if, for example I get x^2 to format it I should basically `System.out.println("x\u00B2")` for printing x²

What if I get a 2 digit power such as x^23 ?

I have the following code for formatting 1 digit powers:

```
//0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
 char[] unicodePowers = {'\u2070','\u00B9','\u00B2','\u00B3','\u2074',
            '\u2075','\u2076','\u2077','\u2078','\u2079'};
 String[] resultPowers = {"^0","^1","^2","^3","^4","^5","^6","^7","^8","^9"};

 for(int i = 0; i < unicodePowers.length; i++){
     expression = expression.replace(resultPowers[i],String.valueOf(unicodePowers[i]));
 }
```

I'm not very familiar with formatting Unicode so I don't know if there is a better approach for solving it.

Thanks!

Comment: Unicode explicitly do not include formatting. So you should not use Unicode characters for exponent (they exist just for compatibility, so everyone could migrate to Unicode, but they should not used for other purposes). Good text needs good font and different layers of formatting libraries. Use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), calling [`.matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) to produce a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). That matcher can [replace all](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) your targeted powers by running our passed [function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html).

```
private static final Pattern EXPONENT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\^(\\d+)");
private static final String NORMAL_LETTERS = "0123456789";
private static final String SUPERSCRIPT_LETTERS =
    "\u2070\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079";

public static String styled(String s) {
    return EXPONENT_PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceAll(mr -> {
        char[] chs = mr.group(1).toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chs.length; ++i) {
            int j = NORMAL_LETTERS.indexOf(chs[i]);
            if (j != -1) {
                chs[i] = SUPERSCRIPT_LETTERS.charAt(j);
            }
        }
        return new String(chs);
    });
}
```

For letters you may search too, https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/phonetic-extensions/
However I do not think there are many superscript math operators.